# sendMessage from backgrond page to another backgrond page chrome extension mv3

Tags: google-chrome-extension, migration, service-worker, sendmessage, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

Migrating extension mv2 to mv3 version. There was a problem with sending messages from one background page to another.

There are two utils (background pages), in order to use the methods of the first in the second and the second in the first, do I need to send messages between these two background pages? or through the main service worker?

I send messages without a service-worker, directly from one utility to another.

```
 chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ type: 'typeMessage' }, (res) => {
      return res;
    });
```

But in another utility the listener does not receive this message

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (message, sender, sendResponse) {
  const { type, payload } = message;

  switch (type) {
    case 'typeMessage':
      // any code
      return;

    default:
      return Promise.resolve(`Message received: ${type}`);
  }
});
```

Please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Sending messages from jsx (foreground) to js (service-worker) works. But from js (background) to another js (background) no.

Comment: We need more information, especially the contents of manifest.json

Comment: There's normally just one background page in ManifestV2. Are you using incognito split mode? Anyway, you're using onMessage incorrectly: returning a value is not supported, only sendResponse is, see https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.

Comment: @ThomasMueller https://codepen.io/Dashevskiy-the-decoder/pen/LYrGEbe

Comment: @wOxxOm , OK. I have a service worker where there is a message listener. I also have two utilities, such as debug and localization. In the debug utility, I need to use certain methods from the localization utility. And in the localization utility, I need to use the methods of the debug utility.
I can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: There's no such term in the extensions API as "utility" so you should show how that code is declared/loaded. Try to make an [MCVE](/help/mcve).

Comment: You can only have one background script in V3 (the extension service worker). But you can [declare that service worker as an ES module](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/mv3-migration/#:~:text=Even%20though%20Manifest%20V3%2C%20does%20not%20support%20multiple%20background%20scripts%2C%20you%20can%20optionally%20declare%20the%20service%20worker%20as%20an%20ES%20Module%20by%20specifying%20%22type%22%3A%20%22module%22%2C%20which%20allows%20you%20to%20import%20further%20code.) and import other scripts. Sorry I can't give you more information. We need to write an article about this.

Comment: The extension system will convert all the background files code into a single background.js file, I'm guessing the ordering of the files mentioned in the manifest would matter. You might need to change the structure of your code as the functions defined in a lower ranked file might not be accessible to the higher raked file. But it's worth a try. Try to use the methods in either of the files as if they were defined in the same file - no need to pass messages. If this doesn't work for the higher ranked file calling a lower ranked file's method, I'm afraid there might be no way around it.